# Use a couple of plugins of jsTree

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have a question?
Is it possible to load only the core file and a few plugins of jsTree?

The jstree.js file in the dist folder is very large and need only a couple of plugins.

How I can load only plugins I need safely?

The plugin url: [jsTree plugin](http://www.jstree.com/plugins/)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no online builder, yet. But you can either:

1) Use a module loader (require, amd, etc) on the `src` folder

2) Concat the ones you need in a single file and minify it.

3) Use the build procedure - clone the repo locally, delete the plugins you do not need from the `src` folder and run the build procedure - the files you need will be in the `dist` folder.